# Is it possible to display all boxes I am currently in?

Tags: tex-core

I'm currently reading Knuth's TeXbook. As an educational reference, is there a way to display a hierarchical list of all boxes I am currently "in" (in other words, I'm typing the document interactively, and at some point, I wish to see the boxes TeX is in the process of creating at the current instant), and ideally, also be able to display their contents?

Knuth mentions the primitive `\showbox`, but it seems (to me) that it requires first for one to run `\setbox`, and furthermore, it seems to tell me nothing about what I have typed so far.

Comment: `\showlists` is what you want here

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
\tracingonline1

aa

\vbox{

bb  \hbox{ccc  \showlists

}}\bye
```

Produces a terminal output of

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (TeX Live 2018) (preloaded format=pdftex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./aa910.tex

### restricted horizontal mode entered at line 7
\tenrm c
\tenrm c
\tenrm c
\glue 3.33333 plus 1.66666 minus 1.11111
spacefactor 1000
### horizontal mode entered at line 7
\hbox(0.0+0.0)x20.0
\tenrm b
\tenrm b
\glue 3.33333 plus 1.66666 minus 1.11111
spacefactor 1000
### internal vertical mode entered at line 5
prevdepth ignored
### vertical mode entered at line 0
### current page:
\glue(\topskip) 5.69446
\hbox(4.30554+0.0)x469.75499, glue set 439.75496fil
.\hbox(0.0+0.0)x20.0
.\tenrm a
.\tenrm a
.\penalty 10000
.\glue(\parfillskip) 0.0 plus 1.0fil
.etc.
total height 10.0
 goal height 643.20255
prevdepth 0.0, prevgraf 1 line

! OK.
l.7 bb  \hbox{ccc  \showlists

?
```

so at the point it stopped

you see you are in a restricted hlist (=hbox)

```
### restricted horizontal mode entered at line 7
\tenrm c
\tenrm c
\tenrm c
\glue 3.33333 plus 1.66666 minus 1.11111
spacefactor 1000
```

That was in an unrestricted hlist (=paragraph *before* it is broken into lines

```
### horizontal mode entered at line 7
\hbox(0.0+0.0)x20.0
\tenrm b
\tenrm b
\glue 3.33333 plus 1.66666 minus 1.11111
spacefactor 1000
```

and the paragraph was in a vertical list from the top of the page that already has a hbox for the line `aa`

```
### vertical mode entered at line 0
### current page:
\glue(\topskip) 5.69446
\hbox(4.30554+0.0)x469.75499, glue set 439.75496fil
.\hbox(0.0+0.0)x20.0
.\tenrm a
.\tenrm a
.\penalty 10000
.\glue(\parfillskip) 0.0 plus 1.0fil
.etc.
```

If you want to see longer lists without being truncated to `etc.` add

```
\showboxbreadth=1000
```

at the top

also

```
\showboxdepth=1000
```

but that makes no difference in this case as this example has no deep nesting.